# Checking if a particular checkbox in a checkbox list is checked

Tags: javascript

I have a list of checkboxes:

```
<input name="choice" type="checkbox" id="choice1" value="A" /> 
<input name="choice" type="checkbox" id="choice2" value="B" />
<input name="choice" type="checkbox" id="choice3" value="C" />
<input name="choice" type="checkbox" id="choice4" value="D" />
```

Name is the same for all but id is different.

I need to check if a particular checkbox (for example the one with id=choice3 is checked.

Tried

```
if (this.choice.id === "choice3" && this.choice[2].checked) {
    alert("checked!");      
}
```

but it does not work - the alert is never reached

P.S. I need to use javascript not jquery

Comment: A simple google search will give you your answer.

Comment: I have tried but nothing work so far, mostly all in JQuery, that's is why I am asking this question

Answer (score 2):

Thats how you do it without jQuery:

Suppose your form is like this:

```
<form id="myForm" action="test.php">
    <input name="choice" type="checkbox" id="choice1" value="A"/>
    <input name="choice" type="checkbox" id="choice2" value="B"/>
    <input name="choice" type="checkbox" id="choice3" value="C"/>
    <input name="choice" type="checkbox" id="choice4" value="D"/>
    <input type="button" onclick="validate();" value="Submit form">
</form>
```

You can do the validation on submit this way:

```
function validate() {

if (document.getElementById('choice3').checked) {
    alert("checked");
} else {
    alert("You didn't check it! ");
}
}
```

Comment: is there a way to do that using `this`? So that it does not stand out from the rest of the code? `this` in this case refers to the current form

Comment: When do you need to check if a checkbox is checked or not? On form submission? If not, please be more precise.

Comment: @HyderB. Can you please do all the work for the OP please.

Comment: Yes, on form submission. When a particular checkbox is checked, another field becomes required, based on whether a particular checkbox is checked or not

Comment: Updated the answer how to do this on form submission.

Comment: that's not what I meant. I wanted to continue using keyword `this` instead of using getElementById. I have decided to go with `if (this.choice[2].checked) { ...}`

Comment: Why are you so obsessed with `this`?!

Comment: Nice manners:) I am not obsessed with `this`, I am just trying to keep the code uniform - the rest of the code uses `this`